# Win32 C++ sendto() Returns Error 8 : WSA_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, udp

I have a program that detects keyboard inputs on my computer and sends them to my Android phone via UDP. The Android phone then takes the UDP packet and logs every key hit in a text file, but that's besides the point. I am currently using the standard Win32 API in order to send the packets via the sendto() function and WSAStartup. However, all of a sudden sendto() keeps returning an error of 8 which, according to MSDN, means WSA_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. Now I have an idea of what that means, but I don't understand how to change my program to fix it, considering I changed nothing and it just started doing it.  Restarting my computer has not helped. Here is what the UDP packet send function looks like.  Maybe you guys can help me. Note that this is a thread function.  Aren't threads dedicated a certain amount of memory according to the programmer?  Could this be the issue?

Edit: This error is received on the PC SENDING the packets, not the phone. Wireshark will not pick up the packing leaving the PC, even though it worked before getting this error.

Thank you,

```
DWORD msgSender(LPVOID arg)
{
//Setup
size_t pkt_length = PACKET_LENGTH;
char pkt[PACKET_LENGTH];
sockaddr_in dest;
sockaddr_in local;
char inputAddr[] = "127.0.0.1";
char destAddr[] = "192.168.1.7";
WSACleanup();
WSADATA WsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WsaData);

local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inputAddr);
local.sin_port = 8081; // choose any

dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(destAddr);
dest.sin_port = htons(8080);

// create the socket
s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
// bind to the local address
bind( s, (sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local) );

while(true)
{
        WaitForSingleObject(msgEvent, INFINITE);
        copyToPacket(keyStr, pkt);
        int ret = sendto( s, pkt, pkt_length, 0, (sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));
        keyReceived = false;
}
return 1;
}

void copyToPacket(string str, char* packet)
{
for(int i = 0; i < str.length() && i < PACKET_LENGTH; i++)
{
    packet[i] = str[i];
}
}
```

Comment: I am thinking this may be an issue of the phone not having the memory to handle the incoming packets. Ensure that you dont have anything in terms of apps running on the phone. Remeber your computer may have gigabytes of memory your phone has a max of 1156MB of ram and maybe 16GB-32GB of HD space.

Comment: Sorry Nomad, maybe I didn't specify enough. This error is on the PC trying to send the packet. It does not know how much memory my phone has, so I do not believe this is the issue. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I see that makes more sense, something to check is to make sure that you dont have some memory leak somewhere. My only suggestion would be to use a memory profiler and take a look at your objects and see what you are actually doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Hmmmm...sendign a keystroke wouldn't take much memory...lemme jingle muh crystal balls a bit...is PACKET_LENGTH set to 8 and are you're using the return value of `sendto` as the error code....maybe?

Comment: Agreed. `8` is not a socket error code, which are in the `10000-11031` range instead, and are always reported by `WSAGetLastError()` (except for in the case of `WSAStartup()`). `WSA_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` is an asynchronous I/O error code instead, which are used by Winsock Extension functions like `WSASendTo()`, not by `sendto()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [sendto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that:

> If no error occurs, sendto returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number indicated by len. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.

From what you've described, it looks like the Windows machine is sending 8 bytes successfully.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. I didn't see that part of the documentation. Thanks for the help!